# Not able to submit mac app for review.

Tags: app-store-connect, mac-app-store

I have uploaded mac app binary and its visible in pre-release section.
The status of the build is uploaded.
But when i click on submit for review I get the message "Please upload build".

Comment: Since the OP is a new user, it would be useful if you could explain the reasons for downvoting the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait they process the build, that usually takes some minutes (at the moment I'm writing).

Status should change to `processing`, and then to `inactive`. When it turns to `inactive` the package icon appear and the build is ready to be used.

Once it is ready, on the version section a plus icon will appear and you will be able to add your build.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how long will it take for processing the build.

Comment: For ios apps it usually takes 10 to 30 minutes, I don't know for a mac app.

Comment: Click + to add a build before you submit your app is not displayed, only submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later or Application loader 3.0 or later is shown.

Comment: What do you see in the prerelease section?

Comment: In prerelease section, status is uploaded.

Comment: Status should change to `Processing`, and then to `Inactive`. When it turns to `inactive` the package icon appear and the build is ready to be used. If there are any errors in your build itunesconnect should warn you. If there are no errors and it stays in status `uploaded` for more than one day I suggest you try to upload it again or contact Apple.